# ASP.NET CORE 2.2 Localization doesn't work on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server, localization

I've been trying to make a simple blog website on .net core 2.2 with Localization. Everything works locally, but on the server, doesn't work.

I added in AssemblyInfo.cs file:
[assembly: RootNamespace("e_cosmetics")]

This is Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("bg-BG")
            };

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("bg-BG");
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

_SelectLanguagePartial.cshtml

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home"
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        @Localizer["Language:"] <select name="culture"
                                        asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Save</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

about.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<section class="about-wrapper">
    <div class="main-nav">
        <h1>@Localizer["За Нас"]</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="index">@Localizer["Начало"]</a></li>
            <li><p>@Localizer["За Нас"]</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="bg-BG" uiCulture="bg-BG" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Resources
[image]

Views.Home.about.en-US.resx
[image]

If somebody give me advice how to fix with the problem, I will be really thankful.

Comment: What are the values of `string culture, string returnUrl` on the server? Don't you have logging?

Comment: **Train** I don't have an access to the server logs.

Comment: Why don't you log errors to the database? Or a file? Try looking at Elmah.

Comment: @Train I did not know about this application. I installed it and tested it.I published the new code to the server, but it not showed any problems.

Comment: If it works on your local but not on the server, obviously something is going on in the server side. It's hard for me to help without more information on what's happening on the server. You're going to have to figure out a way to log more info from the server.

Comment: @Train, the localization just doesn't working on the server and didn't show any kind of problems or errors. Locally it's fine!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem.

> This can occur when a project's name is not a valid .NET identifier. For instance my-project-name.csproj will use the root namespace my_project_name and the assembly name my-project-name leading to this error.
>   Blockquote

I changed the name of the project and folder and now works.